# Error in obtaining request token from JIRA in Oauth Process

Tags: java, python, api, rest, oauth

I am following [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication) to set up the Oauth.

I have set up the the public key , downloaded the jar :

```
   rest-oauth-client-1.0.one-jar.jar
   rest-oauth-client-1.0-sources.jar
```

mentioned on the page,
but when trying to execute :

```
   java -jar rest-oauth-client-1.0.one-jar.jar requestToken https://mycompanyname.atlassian.net
```

I am getting a weird error.. I have set up the consumer key .
Error is :

```
    Jul 01, 2015 3:38:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector handleResponse

WARNING: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Fmycompanyname.atlassian.net", oauth_problem="consumer_key_unknown"}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)

    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain request token

    at com.atlassian.oauth.client.example.AtlassianOAuthClient.getRequestToken(AtlassianOAuthClient.java:66)

    at com.atlassian.oauth.client.example.JIRAOAuthClient.main(JIRAOAuthClient.java:52)

    ... 6 more

Caused by: net.oauth.OAuthProblemException: consumer_key_unknown

    at net.oauth.client.OAuthResponseMessage.toOAuthProblemException(OAuthResponseMessage.java:83)

    at net.oauth.client.OAuthClient.invoke(OAuthClient.java:306)

    at net.oauth.client.OAuthClient.invoke(OAuthClient.java:260)

    at net.oauth.client.OAuthClient.getRequestTokenResponse(OAuthClient.java:190)

    at com.atlassian.oauth.client.example.AtlassianOAuthClient.getRequestToken(AtlassianOAuthClient.java:57)

    ... 7 more
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this error.. 
Please Don't suggest me [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication) link. I've been to this document couple of times.
I've been trying the same with python , but in that I'm not getting how to fetch consumer secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your consumer key must be "hardcoded-consumer" if you are trying to get token with jar rest-oauth-client-1.0.one-jar.jar.

Thanks!